# Issue while trying to pass image and its attributes in an array along with form data

Tags: php, jquery

**About the issue**

I am trying to pass image and its attributes in an array along with other form data.

As there are multiple images being posted so that is why posting array of Uploaded Images. Am I doing anything wrong in below question?

**This below part is not working and below is the output in php.**

[image]

```
var fileData = new FormData();

$.each(Product_Additional_Images, function(index, file) {
    var Product_Sort_No = "1";
    var fileObject = file.files[0];//this is file
    var data = {
        "Image" : fileObject,
        "Sort_No": Product_Sort_No
    }
    fileData.append("Product_Additional_Images[]", JSON.stringify(data));
});

fileData.append('Product_ID', "1");

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url:    "sample url",
    cache:  false,
    async:  true,
    data:   fileData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
    },
    error: function(result) {
    }
});
```

**This one is working perfectly. Below is the one expected output.**

This part is working because only array of images along with form data is being posted. Unfortunately, Image attributes in array is not being passed.

[image]

```
var fileData = new FormData();

$.each(Product_Additional_Images, function(index, file) {
    fileData.append("Product_Additional_Images[]", file.files[0]);
});

fileData.append('Product_ID', "1");

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url:    "sample url",
    cache:  false,
    async:  true,
    data:   fileData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
    },
    error: function(result) {
    }
});
```

Comment: What does `Product_Additional_Images` look like?

Comment: I am expecting it to have two elements in an objects as in first example.

1. Uploaded Image
2. Text

Answer (score 5):

You should send it like so:

```
$.each(Product_Additional_Images, function(index, file) {
  var Product_Sort_No = "1";
  fileData.append("Product_Additional_Images[" + index + "][Image]", file.files[0]);
  fileData.append("Product_Additional_Images[" + index + "][Sort_No]", Product_Sort_No);
});
```

I.e. Use `Product_Additional_Images[{index}]` instead of just `Product_Additional_Images[]`.

### UPDATE

If you want to send the `Image` item as an array of images/files:

```
$.each(Product_Additional_Images, function(index, file) {
  var Product_Sort_No = "1";
  //fileData.append("Product_Additional_Images[" + index + "][Image]", file.files[0]);
  $.each(file.files, function(){
    fileData.append("Product_Additional_Images[" + index + "][Image][]", this);
  });
  fileData.append("Product_Additional_Images[" + index + "][Sort_No]", Product_Sort_No);
});
```

Then in PHP, `$_FILES['Product_Additional_Images']['tmp_name'][0]['Image']` for example, would be an array of files (or temporary files).

Comment: can I make an object with 2 attributes. 1. Uploaded images and 2. Text ?

Comment: Using the `Product_Additional_Images[{index}]` indeed does that. But in PHP, uploaded files are put inside the *superglobal `$_FILES`*. So `$_FILES['Product_Additional_Images']['tmp_name'][0]` for example, allows you to access the *first* image/file, if any. I can update the answer if you need sample *PHP* code?

Comment: I mean, `$_FILES['Product_Additional_Images']['tmp_name'][0]['Image']`. And for the relevant text, use `$_POST['Product_Additional_Images'][0]['Sort_No']`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really notice the "s" as in "1. Uploaded images". Please check the updated answer.